# Javascript work-around for Oracle not having a boolean type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle, extjs, checkbox

I have a web application that uses an Ext.gridEditorGridPanel to display and modify data from an Oracle database.

This works great for displaying string values in textboxes - both for displaying and modifying the data.  However, as I found out after banging my head for some time - it doesn't work for displaying boolean values in checkboxes - because Oracle has no boolean type.

So, I'm going down the road of have the database represent boolean values as 'Y' or 'N' instead of true or false - and attempting to map those to checkboxes I create by hand in the grid.

So far, I've been able to render the checkboxes within the grid and have them displayed correctly as checked or not checked by rendering them by hand like so...

```
{
    dataIndex: 'isActive',
editable: true,
sortable: true,
renderer: function(value) {
    return "<input type='checkbox'" + ((value == 'Y') ? "checked='checked'" : "") + ">";
    },
}
```

However, I've come up short trying to save the values back to the database when the user clicks save.

Really, if I could just figure out how to traverse the grid and get the value of each cell that has a checkbox in it, I could just pass that to a function that updates the data on the server.

So far, I've been able to get a cell like this - but no luck in attempting to determine whether the checkbox within the cell is checked or not...

```
var grid = getMyEditorGridPanel();
grid.getView().getCell(0,1).firstChild
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to implement boolean support layer as close to data source as possible. For that:

1. I'd configure the model field as boolean
2. I'd configure [`trueRe`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/ext/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.field.Boolean-property-trueRe) so that it would evaluate 'Y' as true
3. I'd implement [`serialize`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/ext/5.0.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.field.Boolean-cfg-serialize) function that would convert true and false to 'Y' and 'N' before sending to the server.

This way you can operate in Ext as if Oracle would support boolean.